# Linq to XML using Take() to get first two elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to wrap my head around Linq to XML. I have an XML document that looks like this:

```xml
<update>
    <comments total="4">
        <comment>
            <person>
                <id>SomeID1</id>
                <name>SomeName1</name>
                <picture>PictureURL1</picture>
            </person>
            <message>Comment number 1</message>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <person>
                <id>SomeID2</id>
                <name>SomeName2</name>
                <picture>PictureURL2</picture>
            </person>
            <message>Comment number 2</message>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <person>
                <id>SomeID3</id>
                <name>SomeName3</name>
                <picture>PictureURL3</picture>
            </person>
            <message>Comment number 3</message>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <person>
                <id>SomeID4</id>
                <name>SomeName4</name>
                <picture>PictureUR4L</picture>
            </person>
            <message>Comment number 4</message>
        </comment>
    </comments>
</update>
```

What I want to do is take only the first two comments. This is my code:

```
var commentsList = (from comments in doc.Descendants("comments").Take(2)
                   select comments.Elements("comment"));
```

This works fine if the document has two or less comments, but when there are more than two comments I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'd__11' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement

Am I missing something?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the exception is thrown when I try to use a foreach loop to loop through commentsList. I tried using .ToList() as well but still get the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can jump down directly to the comment element.

```
var commentsList = doc.Descendants("comment").Take(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var commentsList = from comments in doc.Descendants("comments")
                   select comments.Elements("comment").Take(2);
```

Comment: I tried this Ian and I still got the same exception. I forgot to mention that the exception is thrown when I try to use a foreach loop to loop through commentsList. I tried using .ToList() as well but still got the same exception. I'll update my question.